# MVC problem with ID field which is primary key and identity field

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

First of all I am amateur and still learning MVC.
I am making simple app like adress book.

I connected my project with sql database with one table  via entity framework . First row in SQL table is ID which is primary key and identity field. When I auto generate details View and try to run it, I got this error :

"The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in 'Akvizicije_App_1_6.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters "

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)

    {

        Contacts contact = (from k in Context.Contacts

                            where k.idContact == id

                            select k).Single();

        return View(contact);

    }
```

I know there is parameter with int id and it cant be null cuz It is primary key and identity field.
But I dont know how to solve that problem. If someone can help me. 
I would be very thankful. :)

````
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Kontakti</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Zupanija)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Zupanija)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Opcina)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Opcina)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PostanskiBroj)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PostanskiBroj)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NazivNaselja)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NazivNaselja)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NazivUlice)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NazivUlice)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.KucniBroj)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.KucniBroj)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.kcbr)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.kcbr)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Aktivan)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Aktivan)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImeOsobe)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ImeOsobe)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PrezimeOsobe)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PrezimeOsobe)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.KontaktBroj)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.KontaktBroj)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Komentar)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Komentar)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.idKontakt }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>```

Its not on english but you will understand.
````

Comment: When I manualy type /Details/1 it work but how I can solve that it goes automatically. Since I made identity field ID i though that will go automatically.

Comment: Action is called "public ActionResult Details(int id)" Its called from view. How can I make it automatically, whenever I go to details that I proceed correct Id number

Comment: Yea sure. I will update my upper post.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is check your database. Do you have any record there?

Maybe use Find() or FirstOrDefault() function instead query

If you have it on other controller
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Details","ControllerName", null, new { id = Model.idKontakt })

You can use debugger to check what value have id in Details Action

Comment: I have one test entry.

Comment: Maybe you don`t pass the id from your view? 
For Example:

@Html.ActionLink("ShowDetails", "Details", item.id)